# Sort a data structure in Java

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I have a data structure in Java which looks like:

```
class Order {
    int id;
    String name;
    int totalCost;
    String address; 
    List<String> items;

    public setter() {
        .... 
    }

    public getter() {
        ...
    } 
}
```

I have a test class which uses this data structure:

```
class TestClass {
    List<Order> o = getAllOrders();
    sortOrders();
}
```

I want to write a sortOrders method to sort this this data structure based on one of its attributes, in this case the name on the order.

I know to sort in Java we can do:

```
java.util.Collections.sort(anyArrayListOfStrings);
```

What is the efficient way to sort the whole data structure in Java?

Comment: `Collections.sort(o, Comparator.comparing(Order::name))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, all you would need is to pass a comparator to the `Collections.sort()` method. You could do something like this since you want to sort the list of `Order` objects based on the `name` field..

```
Collections.sort(o, new Comparator<Order>() {
    public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {
        return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }
});
```